# Why is my else statement not working correctly?

Tags: java, while-loop

so basically I have a random number generator and if the number is 3, (which is common for the purpose of testing), it will "spawn" a monster and it comes up with a while loop saying that while the monsters health is > 0 keep repeating the while loop, and it says else, say You defeated the monster. But for some reason, it keeps saying You Defeated the Monster when the monsters health is any number, yet still asks me to do another attack. any suggestions?

```
Random dice = new Random();

            for(int counter=1; counter<=3; counter++)
            {
                number = 1+dice.nextInt(3);

                if(number==(3))
                {
                    monster_base_health = 600;
                    monster_base_dmg = 60;
                    System.out.println("A monster appeared!!");

                    while(monster_base_health>0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Would you like to use 1. Fire Blast, 2. Ice Blast, 3. Void Ray? (Just type 1, 2, or 3)");
                        System.out.println();
                        int attack;
                        attack = input.nextInt();
                        if(attack==1)
                        {
                            monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_fire;
                            System.out.println("You used Fire Blast. The Monster now has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
                            System.out.println();

                        }
                        if(attack==2)
                        {
                            monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_iceblast;
                            System.out.println("You used Ice Blast. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        if(attack==3)
                        {   
                            monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_voidray;
                            System.out.println("You used Void Ray. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
                            System.out.println();
                        }   

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("You defeated the monster!!!");

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: In future, please add a tag for the language you're using. I've done it this time :)

Comment: As you are new user here, I would like to tell you, if you get the solution to your problem here, then you should accept the answer to tell others which one worked for you. To accept any answer, you just need to click on the "Right Tick" symbol which will be visible to you on the left side of answer below the up down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

*Fix* the indenting. That should show that the `else` is both *inside* the `while` statement and is attached to [only] the last `if`. That is, the `else` body will execute *every* loop when `!(attack == 3)`.

A solution is then to remove the `else` and place it's body directly *after* the `while` where it is only run after the loop ends because the monster has been killed.

Comment: I think I need to clarify that (attack==3) is a specific spell not the same thing as the random number generator

Comment: @NathanSpangenberg That's fine - *Fix* the identing. Then verify my analysis for yourself, which will be easier when everything is properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are having two if statements and one if-else. To clarify how this thing is going to work, it will check the first if statement `attack == 1`, if it is true then it will execute this block, then it will check second if statement `attack == 2`. It will be false as attack is 1, then it will check the third if statement `attack == 3` it is also false, but this if statement has a else block, so the else block will be executed and it will print, `You defeated the monster`.

To correct your logic, you need to use `Nested if-else`. Try something like,

```
if(attack==1)
{
    monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_fire;
    System.out.println("You used Fire Blast. The Monster now has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    System.out.println();
}
else if(attack==2)
{
    monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_iceblast;
    System.out.println("You used Ice Blast. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    System.out.println();
}
else if(attack==3)
{   
    monster_base_health = monster_base_health - mage_voidray;
    System.out.println("You used Void Ray. The monster has " + monster_base_health + " health!");
    System.out.println();
}   
else
{
    System.out.println("You defeated the monster!!!");
}
```

In this logic, the else block will be executed only if all the three if statements are false.

Comment: This change still doesn't make sense and suffers from the core problem as the original: it will tell the user they defeated the monster after entering an invalid attack (eg. 4), but it won't tell them when they *actually* defeated the monster. However, formatting the code like this does make the issue much more apparent.